# flutter http invalid header name

Tags: http, flutter

I got a problem with the header.

> Invalid header field name, with 128

One important thing FYI, *when I use the JSON MOCK SERVER, it works very well*, after switching DOCKER environment I got the error. I would like to add other details. I also test my real back-end code which is works on the docker environment, **I test on the browser with fetch API, and also angular application works well**. *I think that there is not related to my back-end or such kind of CORS issues.*

```dart
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
   final String url = '$baseUrl/login';

   try {
     final http.Response response = await http.post(
       url,
       headers: <String, String>{
         HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
       },
       body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
         'email': email,
         'password': password,
         'device_name': 'apple',
       }),
     );

     if (response.statusCode != 200) {
       throw HttpException('An error occured ${response.statusCode}');
     }

     if (response.statusCode == 422) {
       throw UnprocessableEntity('form values not okay');
     }

     final Login user = Login.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

     _token = user.data.token;
     _email = email;

     final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
         await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     final userData = json.encode({
       'token': _token,
       'email': _email,
     });
     sharedPreferences.setString('userData', userData);

     notifyListeners();
   } catch (exception) {
     throw exception;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The network has been hijacked. Maybe you should consider HTTPS

Comment: Issue has been solved. The problem was backend application response header. Header was added unnecessary empty space to response data which flutter couldn’t handle it.